# Border-radius transition not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions

I'm working on a small page, and one of the sections will contain an image gallery. The original pictures are squares, but on the page I set the border-radius to 50% and then when you hover above an image the radius goes to 0% and the image also scale to 1.4.

This works fine, but I also want to add a div with text in front of the image when you hover. This text will contain some information, and it will be a bit transparent so you can see the image behind it. The code below works fine in IE, Chrome and FF, but Safari just don't want to cooperate. When the scale property of the image works, the border-radius wont, and vice versa.

HTML

```
<div class="bild">
        <img src="img/Soffa2.png">
          <div class="bild_text">
            <div class="bild_textrad">
              <h2>SoffaDirekt</h2>
              <p>Concept</p>
              <a href="#">Read more!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.bild {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-property: border-radius;
  transition-duration: .8s;
}

.bild:hover{
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.bild > img {
  max-width: 102%;
  max-height: 102%;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .8s;
}

.bild:hover > img{
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.bild_text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(23 , 23, 23, 0.5);
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .8s, visibility .8s;
}

.bild:hover > .bild_text{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several properties in CSS which need prefix -webkit- applied before them just like

```
.bild {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: border-radius; /* Safari */
          transition-property: border-radius;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;  /* Safari */
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

`version 3.1 to 6.1` of safari support `transition-property` and `transition-duration` with `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: Do I need to add the webkit prefix to all transition and transform elements?

Comment: Yes, if your Safari browser version is older than 6.1. Otherwise the browser won't understand these properties. You can always visit W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-property.asp
to check for browser support if ever in doubt.
Cheers!!